# AF_UNIX socket connect failed with errno 111

Tags: c, sockets

```
static void
openlog_internal(const char *ident, int logstat, int logfac)
{
    if (ident != NULL)
        LogTag = ident;
    LogStat = logstat;
    if (logfac != 0 && (logfac &~ LOG_FACMASK) == 0)
        LogFacility = logfac;

    int retry = 0;
    while (retry < 2) {
        if (LogFile == -1) {
            SyslogAddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
            (void)strncpy(SyslogAddr.sun_path, _PATH_LOG,
                      sizeof(SyslogAddr.sun_path));
            if (LogStat & LOG_NDELAY) {
              LogFile = __socket(AF_UNIX, LogType | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0);
              if (LogFile == -1)
                return;
            }
        }
        if (LogFile != -1 && !connected)
        {
            int old_errno = errno;
            if (__connect(LogFile, &SyslogAddr, sizeof(SyslogAddr))
                == -1)
            {
                int saved_errno = errno;
                int fd = LogFile;
                LogFile = -1;
                (void)__close(fd);
                __set_errno (old_errno);
                if (saved_errno == EPROTOTYPE)
                {
                    /* retry with the other type: */
                    LogType = (LogType == SOCK_DGRAM
                           ? SOCK_STREAM : SOCK_DGRAM);
                    ++retry;
                    continue;
                }
            } else
                connected = 1;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Above is part of the GNU libc syslog source file. It is about opening syslog socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, with sun_path set to "/dev/log"). But when I change to sun_path other path or use abstract socket the __connect() will return errno 111.

1. I also replace __connect() with connect(). but the same errno
2. As far as I know, for SOCK_DGRAM, the connect() function will set the socket default sendto/recvfrom address, so we can use recv() later on this socket.
3. socket bind() can assign an address to a socket, when I add bind() before the call of connect(), connect() will success. Why this standard libc didn't use bind() before call connect().

Comment: `bind()` before `connect()` is not necessary. What did you bind to?

Comment: bind() to SyslogAddr(the same address as the address going to send to). if didn't use bind(), how can the system know the sending socket when use send(), but glibc seems didn't use bind()

Comment: The _sending socket_ is identified by its descriptor which is passed as _send()_'s first argument, so _the system know_ it. If you rather mean a sending address - such is not needed for _syslog_ as it won't send anything in return. In general, only a listening socket (server) has to _bind()_, not a connecting socket (client).